# Angular2: How to instantiate the state of the checkbox in FormGroup?

Tags: forms, angular, checkbox

Friends, I have some form in angular 2 app. In component I use form group like this:

```
this.formPersonalProfile = new FormGroup({
            private: new FormControl(false),
});
```

In template of this component I described checkbox as follow:

```
<input type="checkbox" private="private" formControlName="private" class="form-check-input">
```

OK, after this I open this template in popup window via ngbModal, and I see that my checkbox is unchecked. But when I try to see FormGroup in console, I see that this field of FormGroup is null. Only if I manually click on checkbox, I get needed value.

Can I set the default value of checkbox via FormGroup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you gave is a little lean, but here's a shot at getting the checkbox to properly bind.

Your input may not be nested in a marked formGroup like so

```
<form [formGroup]="formPersonalProfile">
    <input type="checkbox" private="private" formControlName="private" class="form-check-input" />
</form>
```

And make sure you have imported ReactiveFormsModule in your app module

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms"

// later
@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
```

Here's a working Plunker that should give you the desired behavior:
 http://plnkr.co/edit/ryQ3G5p165XaXzJHcxUv?p=preview